# When a Muslim passes away (dies) - what happens?

Tags: death, day-of-judgement

When a Muslim passes away, what happens to them?

What does Allah SWT do? I mean, do they just wait until judgemental day to see what will happen to them?

It's hard to understand that someone whom you love so much is just in the grave and there is nothing that can be done/know what is happening to them.

What does Islam/Allah say about this? Do they go straight into peace/comfort in (Inshallah) Junnah? (Heaven)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to hadith, you will be questioned by two angels in three regards: who you worshipped, who Muhammad is, and what religion you followed. Depending on your answers, your wait in the grave - which lasts until judgement day - is made easy, or torturous. For details, there are many collections of relevant ahadith online, for example [here](https://islamqa.info/en/10403).

Comment: Thank you. I, needless to say, worry about myself but also family members who have passed away hence my question.